# Manga about a manga author and elf drawing things together

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga sometime back then. It's about a guy drawing manga art and one of his characters, which is an elf, comes out from his manga and then ended up blowing up his apartment or house.

Please let me know if you know what manga this is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: I read it this year and it's in black and white

Comment: Do you recall any other details about what happened? Did it have a distinctive art style? Was it a one-shot or a longer series? Did the characters have any defining features?

Comment: It was a longer series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably *[Does a Hot Elf Live Next Door to You?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/does-a-hot-elf-live-next-door-to-you)*.

> **High schooler Inudo Keita dreams of being a great mangaka**. He also happens to live in a Japan that mingles with the denizens of strange and fantastical alternate worlds. When a gorgeous **pyromaniac elf** moves into the apartment next door, Keita’s life flies off the rails–and she’s only the first otherworldly girl to throw his life into chaos. Will Keita be able to complete a single manga page without a beautiful woman turning his day into a hot, flaming mess? (Probably not!)

It's not a perfect match - the elf does not come from his manga. She's an elf from another world that was looking for the author of a manga, and finds him as he just finished drawing some elf smut and was about to submit it as a contest entry. After some sexual harassment, she blows up his apartment complex,

[image]

Chapter 7 has her helping him with the manga, but she's not doing any drawing herself. Rather, she appears to be using her magic to act as a photo reference in a way that it can be copied on to paper.

[image]

Comment: Thanks been looking for this for a while